# Android app. HTML content embedded

Tags: android, html

I'm developing an application with HTML embedded content in the main activity showing a webpage. I'm using the class `android.webkit.WebViewClient`

When the user clicks a link, I don't want the target HTML content to be embedded again in my app. I'd like that this URL be handled by the installed browser.

Is it possible? I did not see anything in the API for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that control myself, however, my thought process would be:

1. Is there a `OnNavigated` or something similar event (Triggered when the `WebViewClient` starts navigating to another page.
2. If so, then I would check in that event for the `URL's` value. If it is not your webpage, then launch an `Intent` with the `URL` as the `URI`.
3. Failing all of these, I would be searching for a way to display a webpage without using a `WebViewClient`